# How to EnablePrivateGalleries in Visual Studio 2015 Isolated Shell

Tags: visual-studio-2015, vsix, vsx, visual-studio-shell

I have Visual Studio 2015 Isolated Shell app and i have enabled private galleries by setting enable value as per instruction in application.pkgdef

"EnablePrivateGalleries"=dword:00000000

But unable to see option to configure in Extension Manager dialog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be: `"EnablePrivateGalleries"=dword:00000001`

> // Support for end-user customization of extension galleries is
>   disabled by default.
>
> // Uncomment the following to enable end-user customization of
>   extension galleries
>
> // that appear in the Extension Manager dialog.
>
> "EnablePrivateGalleries"=dword:00000001

[image]

Comment: Thanks , it worked ...but when i try to install package from pvt gallery it says it doesn't support product. i have marked installed target to the name of my isolated shell...if any clue .

Comment: @Rajat You can post a new question and attach the detailed settings and screenshots so that we can check.